# How to insert sequential numbers in primary key using select subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am reading a table A and inserting the date in Table B (both tables are of same structure except primary key data type). In Table B, Primary key is int whereas in Table A it is UniqueIdentifier.

INSERT INTO TableB
(ID, Names, Address)
(select ID, Names, Address from TableA)

Now how can i insert int type incremental value (1,2,3,so on) in TableB instead of uniqueidentifier from TableA using above script.

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not change Table B so that the primary key is an identity which auto-increments?

Comment: Would you please provide an example of how to set up an auto-increment identity PK?

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks casperOne, it was really easy.

Comment: Perhaps @sunk was using MySQL and an InnoDB table. In that case, using AUTO_INCREMENT would not be the best idea. AUTO_INCREMENT does not work the same in an InnoDB table as it does in a MyISAM table..

Answer (score 2):

Go to the table properties, select the ID field, under "Identity specification", set "Identity Increment" = 1, "Identity Seed" = 1. By doing that, the ID becomes auto incremental...

Then your insert statement would be something like:

`INSERT INTO TableB (Names, Address) (select Names, Address from TableA)`

Answer (score 2):

If changing the schema of your TableB is not an option then add a rank to your select statement like this:

```
insert into tableB select rank() over(order by id), name, address from tableA
```

This will always start at 1.  I you could add + 10 if you wanted to start your numbering at a number other than 1.  I'm sure you get the idea from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TableB
(
  ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  Name nvarchar(200),
  Address nvarchar(200)
)
```

Then, in the query, don't specify the value of the identity column.

```
INSERT INTO TableB(Name, Address)
SELECT Name, Address FROM TableA
```